# How to revert from rpi-update to stable build

Tags: raspbian, kernel, firmware, crash, rpi-update

I have been using a RPi3 for the last year without any issues. I have had `rpi-update` as part of a regular update process (`cron` job).
Lately I have been experiencing crashes. I started to investigate, and while there is nothing helpful in the syslog I saw a new warning message that `rpi-update` updates to pre-releases of the linux kernel tree and Videocore firmware. That might be causing my crashing problems.

So how do I roll back to the latest stable Videocore firmware and kernel without reinstalling Raspbian?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> "In normal circumstances there is NEVER a need to run rpi-update as it always gets you to the leading edge firmware and kernel and because that may be a testing version it could leave your RPi unbootable". https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=916911#p916911
>   Even the [rpi-update](https://github.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update) documentation now warns "Even on Raspbian you should only use this with a good reason. This gets you the latest bleeding edge kernel/firmware."

`sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install --reinstall raspberrypi-bootloader raspberrypi-kernel`
will put it back to the latest supported kernel/bootcode.

Comment: Do that today and you'll get exactly the same kernel and firmware. Because they've rebuilt the Raspbian packages in last week. But your advice is generally the recommended process.

Comment: Thanks for the reinstall command - that was what I needed. Since the warning is now coming up when you call `rpi-update` I am aware of the problem.